# what does it mean to call DataBind() on a GridView in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm pretty new to asp.net and I came across a page with a GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GV" runat="server"
        OnRowCancelingEdit="GV_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="GV_RowUpdating"
        OnRowEditing="GV_RowEditing" OnRowDeleting="GV_RowDeleting" OnRowDataBound="GV_RowDataBound"
        GridLines="None" CssClass="tbl1" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alternate"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

And in the C# code I see that there are methods for each "OnRow" type attribute. What exactly would you want a gridView for? Is this just a fancy html table that allows you to have onChange events?

And what does calling the function DataBind() do exactly?

I've attempted to look this up on the msdn page but it wasn't too clear. If someone could show me a few links on a good tutorial for girdViews I'd appreciate it.

Comment: basically just says bind this grid's datasource to the grid itself

Comment: The MSDN documentation (and the additional articles elsewhere on the web) on the subject is *quite* expansive.  You should really focus your question much more specifically than just "explain GridView", because that's just too broad of a topic for the site, and the documentation is actually quite detailed.  If a specific aspect of the documentation confuses you, explain what specific thing you don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this just a fancy html table that allows you to have onChange
>   events?

Yes. It is just a fancy HTML table with [other events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). But it is a [server side control](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306459)

> what does calling the function DataBind() do exactly?

It binds the `DataSource` specified with the `GridView` to the Grid. For example if you have

```
DataTable SomeDataTable = //filled with a result from a SQL Query
gridView1.DataSource = SomeDataTable;
gridView1.DataBind();
```

Here `DataBind` will attach the data in `SomeDataTable` to your grid.

Comment: The DataTable that you're creating, is that the equivalent of a variable declared on the stack that has the same structure as the query that's being made? ie SomeDataTable is just an object with the rows that were pulled from the SQL query? Thanks for the explanation

Comment: and would the query being made have to return the exact columns/rows as set up in the GridView?

Comment: The query doesn't need to return the Exact same columns as that in the Gridview. It should have all of those present in the gridview but can also have some extra too. It's up to you whether you want to display them on the gridview or not.